# Moving Nexus (same version) from one server to another

Tags: migration, nexus

I want to move my Nexus 2 from one server to another, keeping the version same.

I can see documentation on [upgradation](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/upgrading) & [migration from other repository tools](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager2/migrating), but not for moving same version.

Any suggestions?

*Thank you*

Answer (score 3):

Just copy/paste the folders from one server to the other and make sure that users/priviledges are set correctly.

Since installing Nexus is just unzipping, you do not need to do anything else.

Comment: Thanks, where are the users/privileges data stored?

Comment: The `sonatype-work` contains all users/priviledges/data except for some configuration regarding ports etc.